# Spring Batch + Spring Data + Hibernate/JPA: runtime of processor slows down with each chunk

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Boot application using spring batch and spring data (JPA/Hibernate). In one of my batches I am processing entity A and for each of the entities I am using information from entity B. Entity B is loaded in the process function of my custom ItemProcessor using a JPA repository using a findBy method.

In my current test scenario I am processing about 8000 entries of entity type A. The chunk size is set to 1000, though i experimented with 100 and 10000 as well. What I have seen (using step and chunk listeners) is that with each chunk, the time the application takes to execute the findBy method of the repository increases. So in the first chunk the average time to execute the function is 5ms. In the next chunk already 10ms, in the third about 15ms and it continues to increase with each chunk.

From my experiments with the Chunk size I have seen, that increasing the chunk size improved the overall performance of the batch job, whereas a smaller chunk size increases the run time of the batch job.

Apart from any improvements I could do on the modelling of the entities and its relations to each other (including fetching), I am wondering which mechanism is playing a main role here. Do you have any idea?

```
timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
entityB= entityBRepository.findByEntityAReference(entityA.getReference());
timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info("Time to read from Repository: " + (timeAfter - timeBefore));
```

This is the code block that is slowing down with each chunk. The repository is just defined as an interface.

```
public interface EntityBRepository extends JpaRepository<Domain, Long>
```

Do you think it's rather an issue coming from Spring Batch or from using JPA, Hibernate and Spring Data?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: @SteveFest Please don't yell. You may propose an edit for that.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will try to calm myself down before posting.